# Python function with request might hang, how to timeout?

Tags: python, multithreading, request, timeout

I'm building a script to process messages using the O365 module (https://pypi.org/project/O365/).
The script runs great but for some reason, after a random time (usually about 20 hours) it get's stuck on a request without response and the script just hangs there waiting for a response.

It's not a server throttling issue as I've slowed my script down to one request every minute and it still hangs.

I think it might be a bug in O365 module where it doesn't timeout the requests, so I'm thinking on making the calls on a separate thread and if it doesn't return in a certain amount of time, kill it.
But from what I understand, if I just try to join the thread it will try to wait until it finishes (which is never), is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, In order to help you, provide some code in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use multithreading and the [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) method. As explained in the documentation: "This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called terminates – either normally or through an unhandled exception – or until the optional timeout occurs."
Your request will either terminate because it has been completed or because the maximum time limit has been reached.